# Fakepath Javamail alternativas

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, email-attachments

I have the typical code to send emails by JavaMail but when sending an attachment I get this message:

> error -{"ERROR":"IOException while sending message"}

In my project I only use Java, JavaScript and ajax. This is working in Eclipse.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  If you are asking us to help you get your code working, you need to show us your code and a stacktrace.  If you are asking us to identify an alternative mail library: 1) that is off-topic, and 2) in order to identify an alternative **that will solve your problem** we need to understand why javax.mail is not working for you. (There is a good chance that the real cause of problem is that you are using javax.mail incorrectly, or the mail server you are talking to is refusing to accept overly large emails ... or something like that.)

Comment: In addition to all the above...  What does the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show?